# Handling URL's encoded with ISO-8859-1 in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: asp.net-core, httprequest, url-encoding

We are dealing with some financial institutions that send us requests encoded in ISO-8859-1. They post back to us during an authentication flow, where the query string is ISO-8859-1 encoded (some characters in the request query use Å, ä etc). How do you configure ASP.NET Core API controllers to correctly give us the decoded parameters? The default (UTF-8) obviously does not work correctly. Previous API such as 
`HttpUtility.UrlDecode(request.Value, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(28591))`
seem to have vanished (or are not yet there) in .NET Core RTM.

Our workaround is to create a separate util lib with the above encoding call that cannot target .NET Core.

Is there a way to configure request encoding in web.config or any other proper way of dealing with this?

Comment: Please use the package search, http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=System.Text.Encoding%20GetEncoding. The GetEncoding method is still there, you just need to reference a certain package (frameworkAssemblies section of a framework target) or add it as dependency to project.json

Comment: Yes, GetEncoding is still there - but what we really need is HttpUtility.UrlDecode- [packagesearch](http://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/?q=UrlDecode) which takes an encoding argument - which is no longer present.